# List of filenames force only one filename in each element

Tags: r, list, csv, unique, element

I am performing a file search in R for .csv data files in the same directory for a string range based on user input. The string is a Julian build date code in the filename, so there can be multiple files with the build date code in the name, but the rest of the file name is different for each unit (see output example below).  I want a list of these filenames for a build code date range, one filename per list element. I am able to get one filename per list element *except* when two files have that same build code, then they are put together in one element.  This crashes my read.csv call when two file names are in the same element:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

This list of filenames will become a list of dataframes, one per element, so they can't be mixed. How can I specify that only one filename goes in each list element?

---

Problematic Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "C:/...125872C15278001781_20180417_095231.csv"

[[2]]
[1] "C:/...125872D15309005835_20180516_150200.csv"

[[3]]
[1] "C:/...125872D15314006345_20180516_151817.csv"

[[4]]
[1] "C:/...125872D16178000189_20180516_150743.csv"

[[5]]
[1] "C:/...125872E**16313**000033_20180516_141938.csv"<BR>
[2] "C:/...125872E**16313**000129_20180314_092803.csv"
```

---

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
[[1]]
[1] "C:/...125872C15278001781_20180417_095231.csv"

[[2]]
[1] "C:/...125872D15309005835_20180516_150200.csv"

[[3]]
[1] "C:/...125872D15314006345_20180516_151817.csv"

[[4]]
[1] "C:/...125872D16178000189_20180516_150743.csv"

[[5]]
[1] "C:/...125872E16313000033_20180516_141938.csv"

[[6]]
[1] "C:/...125872E16313000129_20180314_092803.csv"
```

---

Psuedo-code (not allowed to upload files):

```
Fun.tempFile <- function(y){

  tempfileName <- paste0(workingDirectory, "/EEPROM_Dump_*", y, "*.csv", collapse = "")

  tempfileName2 <- Sys.glob(tempfileName, dirmark = FALSE) 
  tempfileName2

  return(tempfileName2)
}

dateCodeRange <- as.character(c(begDateJ:endDateJ))

dateCodeFileNamesAll <- (c(lapply(dateCodeRange, Fun.tempFile)))

filenames <- unique(dateCodeFileNamesAll[lapply(dateCodeFileNamesAll,length)>0] )

myData = lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = FALSE)
```

Comment: How about `filenames<-as.list(unlist(filenames))` before the final line?

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you so much.